# redirecting to a different page in blazor

Tags: blazor

```
<MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Button" OnClick="" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ml-auto">Cancel</MudButton>
```

Pressing this button must navigate to another page. How do I do this in blazor?
In javascript we use DOM object to set the href. Not sure how we do in blazor

Comment: See `NavigationManager.NavigateTo()` for a c# solution. FYI: you can also use html tag `<a>` if there is no other logic executed when clicking on the button: it is better for the user to know where the link redirects.

Answer (score 5):

Inject `NavigationManager` and then use `NavigationManager.NavigateTo(<your URL>);`.

Comment: `@onclick='() => _navigationManager.NavigateTo("path to page")'`